# How to do get value from custom geojson prop without properties for paint expression in Mapbox

Tags: expression, mapbox-gl-js

I want to change features style according to in features style property. But style is not in properties. A sample feature is like that,

```
{
   type:"feature",
   style:{polygon:{"line-color":"#FF0000"}},
   properties:{...},
  geometry:{...}
}
```

So, according to documents 'get' expression does not work. Because, it looks for property section [Document Mapbox Expressions](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#get).

I was wondering, are there any method to get information from style section in the features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in a style, there is no way to access any part of an object other than in the `properties` section. (The one exception to this is the `id` property).

You will need to process your data differently.

Comment: As by https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#get *Retrieves a property value from the current feature's properties, or from another object if a second argument is provided* but there is no example on how to use it and cannot figure it out.

Comment: That extra argument lets you do things like access an attribute from within an object that is stored in a feature property. It doesn't let you access parts of the GeoJSON object outside its `properties` member.

Comment: Uh, I understand now. Thanks.